# Using ProgressMonitorDialog in Eclipse 4 properly

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I have a set of APIs that do file operations e.g. `saveToFile(CustomObject objectToSave);`

Since a file operation could be lengthy I decided that some indication should be shown to the user e.g. progress bar.

I read about a `ProgressMonitorDialog` and so I tried it, but it doesn't exactly work as I need (or better I don't know how to use it properly).

Currently I do:

```
ProgressMonitorDialog progressDialog = new ProgressMonitorDialog(theShell);  
    try {  
        progressDialog.run(false, true, new IRunnableWithProgress() {  

        @Override  
        public void run(IProgressMonitor monitor) throws InvocationTargetException, InterruptedException {  
            monitor.beginTask("Saving your data", 100);  
            try {  
                Utils.saveToFile(objectToSave);  
            } catch (Exception e) {  
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
                e.printStackTrace();  
            }  
            monitor.done();   
        }  
     });
```

This code shows a progress dialog very fast and ends, but the problem is that on a slower PC this would stack until the `Utils.saveToFile` returned, while I have no idea how to indicate intermediate process until the save is completed.

I found a [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7636020/how-can-i-correctly-update-a-progress-bar-for-an-operation-of-unknown-duration-w) mentioning about `IProgressMonitor.UNKNOWN` but it does not say about what happens in `monitor` during the `performRead(_fileName, monitor);`

How would I solve this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`ProgressMonitorDialog` is a tricky piece of code. I guess the part you are missing is [`IProgressMonitor#worked(int)`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/runtime/IProgressMonitor.html#worked%28int%29) which will "grow" the progress bar. Below is a code example that should clarify how to use it:

```
public class Progress {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // Create your new ProgressMonitorDialog with a IRunnableWithProgress
        try {
            // 10 is the workload, so in your case the number of files to copy
            IRunnableWithProgress op = new YourThread(10);
            new ProgressMonitorDialog(new Shell()).run(true, true, op);
         } catch (InvocationTargetException ex) {
             ex.printStackTrace();
         } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
             ex.printStackTrace();
         }
    }

    private static class YourThread implements IRunnableWithProgress
    {
        private int workload;

        public YourThread(int workload)
        {
            this.workload = workload;
        }

        @Override
        public void run(IProgressMonitor monitor) throws InvocationTargetException, InterruptedException
        {
            // Tell the user what you are doing
            monitor.beginTask("Copying files", workload);

            // Do your work
            for(int i = 0; i < workload; i++)
            {
                // Optionally add subtasks
                monitor.subTask("Copying file " + (i+1) + " of "+ workload + "...");

                Thread.sleep(2000);

                // Tell the monitor that you successfully finished one item of "workload"-many
                monitor.worked(1);

                // Check if the user pressed "cancel"
                if(monitor.isCanceled())
                {
                    monitor.done();
                    return;
                }
            }

            // You are done
            monitor.done();
        }

    }
}
```

It will look something like this:

[image]

For your special case of using `Utils.saveToFile` you could hand the `IProgressMonitor` over to this method and call the `worked()` method from there.

Comment: +1. I used a `FutureTask` and "polled" the `isDone` adding `1` to the `monitor.worked(1);` to make the task bar grow.I want to display progress while 1 file is updated.But I am wondering if it is inappropriate in eclipse application

Comment: @Cratylus If you can think of an appropriate method to visualise the file update, why not? I don't think that it is inappropriate, as long as the execution time really justifies using a progress bar.

Comment: `as long as the execution time really justifies using a progress bar`.Interesting comment.You mean that in my case perhaps it is too much?What other option would be more appropriate for an action that could potentially delay?

Comment: @Cratylus I really can't estimate how long this operation could last. If you yourself don't know it in advance, then use a progress dialog. If you are sure that it is a task that can be done in less than a second or two, then I would suggest just doing it in another thread. BTW: If you don't know how to visualise the progress, you can always use the `IProgressMonitor.UNKNOWN` as mentioned in your question.

Comment: My best guess is that it can be between 1-5 seconds.

Comment: @Cratylus Then I would go for a progress dialog, even if it just flashes in some cases.

Comment: If you are not busy, would you check this one?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12988546/how-can-i-export-an-eclipse-4-application-for-multiple-platforms

Comment: Hello, do you have any suggestion for handling properly the two exceptions?