# ProgressMonitorDialog - Watching active thread to update monitor

Tags: java, multithreading, swt, progress-bar

In my GUI I have a PDF file creation operation.  The operation can take up to 10-15 seconds to complete. When I start the operation, I attach a listener to it.  The listener changes the cursor and disables the GUI, until the operation completes.
I would also like to add a progressbar, so the users will have a idea when it is going to complete.

Created a method startProgressBar() and called it from the start of the operation method.
*See Below:*

```
  private void startSavePdfOperation() {
      startProgressBar();
      saveOp = new AplotSaveOperation(appReg.getString("aplot.message.SAVETOPDF"), "PDF", session);
      saveOp.addOperationListener(new MyOperationListener(this) {
```

*startProgressBar Method - See Below:*

```
 public void startProgressBar() {
     Shell shell = new Shell(getShell());
  shell.setSize(260, 120);
  final ProgressBar bar = new ProgressBar(shell, SWT.SMOOTH);
  bar.setBounds (20, 20, 200, 20);
  shell.open();
  final int maximum = bar.getMaximum();
  new Thread(new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
        for (final int[] i = new int[1]; i[0] <= maximum; i[0]++) {
        try {Thread.sleep (100);} catch (Throwable th) {}
           if (Display.getDefault().isDisposed()) return;
           Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
              public void run() {
              if (bar.isDisposed ()) return;
                 bar.setSelection(i[0]);
              }
           });
        }
     }
  }).start();
```

The code above created the ProgressBar.  The issue is that the operation would end well before the progressbar indicator was close to ending.

Question:  Is this because in the method I am creating a new thread and the indicator is updating according to the new thread and not the operation thread?

Question:  Is it possible to create a new thread that watches the GUI thread and updates the progressbar accordingly?

Read a article suggesting using ProgressMonitorDialog with IRunnableWithProgress.

*Method startProgressBar using ProgressMonitorDialog - see below:*

```
 public void startProgressBar() {
  ProgressMonitorDialog dialog = new ProgressMonitorDialog(getShell());    
  try {
     dialog.run(true, true, new IRunnableWithProgress(){
          public void run(IProgressMonitor monitor) {
              monitor.beginTask("Some nice progress message here ...", 100);
              ** getThread(); **
              monitor.done();
          }
      });
  }
  catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
  }
  catch (InterruptedException e) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
  } 
}

 public void getThread() {
   new Thread etc.. etc...

 }
```

It seems that it will have the same issues with threading and updating as the code above.

Question:  So now I am thinking can I just add or update the ProgressBar to my existing Listener

*OperationListener Code - see below:*

```
 public abstract class MyOperationListener implements InterfaceAIFOperationListener {
  AplotCreatePDFDialog w = null;

  public MyOperationListener(AplotCreatePDFDialog win) {
     w = win;
  } 
  public void startOperation(String startMessage) {
     Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
           w.getShell().setCursor(new Cursor(Display.getCurrent(), SWT.CURSOR_WAIT));
           w.recursiveSetEnabled(getShell(), getShell().getEnabled());
           w.getShell().setEnabled(!getShell().getEnabled());
        }
     });
  } 

  public void endOperation() {
     try {
        endOperationImpl();
     }
     finally {
        Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
           public void run() {
              w.getShell().setCursor(new Cursor(Display.getCurrent(), SWT.CURSOR_ARROW));
              w.recursiveSetEnabled(getShell(), true);
              w.getShell().setEnabled(!getShell().getEnabled());
              w.close();
           }
        });
     }
  } 
  abstract protected void endOperationImpl();
} // end class MyOperationListener
```

Thanks for any help you can give me with this.

***EDIT***

Baz, your answer below is exactly what the question asked, so thank you for answering.

But I am starting to think that what I am trying to do is not possible.
When my operation starts, I wanted the progress bar indicator to start and when my operation ended I wanted the indicator be at the end and the monitor would close.

I thought there might bee a way to use my listener to add the progressbar.  Something like the following.

```
 public void startOperation(String startMessage) {
     Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
           ->monitor.beginTask("Creating PDF File(s)", IProgressMonitor.UNKNOWN);<-
           w.getShell().setCursor(new Cursor(Display.getCurrent(), SWT.CURSOR_WAIT));
           w.recursiveSetEnabled(getShell(), getShell().getEnabled());
           w.getShell().setEnabled(!getShell().getEnabled());

        }
     });
  } 
  public void endOperation() {
     try {
        ->monitor.worked(1);<-
        endOperationImpl();
     }
     finally {
        Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
           public void run() {
              w.getShell().setCursor(new Cursor(Display.getCurrent(), SWT.CURSOR_ARROW));
              w.recursiveSetEnabled(getShell(), true);
              w.getShell().setEnabled(!getShell().getEnabled());
              ->monitor.done();<-
              w.close();
           }
        });
     }
  } 
  abstract protected void endOperationImpl();
```

} // end class MyOperationListener

But I am starting to see that the ProgressBar has to have some sort of measurement to display the indicator correctly.

I would be happy if the indicator just went back and forth and the monitor would close at the end of the operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use [`ProgressMonitorDialog`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjface%2Fdialogs%2FProgressMonitorDialog.html)?

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12987522/1449199) is a related answer from me showing a simple example.

This is what it looks like:

[image]

---

If you are not sure about the workload, use this code:

```
monitor.beginTask("Copying files", IProgressMonitor.UNKNOWN);
```

It will show the idle bar while running.

Comment: I have added the code for a ProgressMonitordialog.  I created a method that handles the try and creates the Dialog.  I added the YourThread Class.  Should I call the progressbar method inside the startOperation method in my listener?  Also I understand that workload is how the progress is measured.  But I do not have a average time it takes to complete the operation.  It could by 5 secs to 20 seconds. So I am not sure how to handle the workload - But I do like this dialog better and thanks for your help thus far.

Comment: @jkteater I edited my answer with some example code for handling unknown workload. As for the placement of the code. Doing it in the listener should be fine.

Comment: @jkteater If you see my answer, there is a line using `IProgressMonitor.UNKNOWN` which will make the bar go back and forth. There is no other way if you don't know how long it will take. The dialog will close once you call `monitor.done();`.

Comment: Sorry for not fully understanding your answer.  I know that the answer is right, I am just trying to figure out how to use it correctly. I did add the IProgressMonitor.UNKNOWN. But now the run method in the YourThread Class only has monitor.beginTask, then monitor.done().  So it basically opens and closes.  If both begin and done is in the same run, how do I tell it to stay open?