# SWT Modal ProgressBar loose Window focus

Tags: java, swt

I have a Modal Dialog making tasks with a thread.
This works well except that the main window is no longer focusable, in the OS task bar clicking on my application icon has no effect, this type of event is frozen, it's a problem when other windows are over and I want to show it again.

(I use SWT only, no JFace)

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Dialog;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.ProgressBar;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

public class ProgressBox extends Dialog {

    protected Shell dialog;
    protected ProgressBar bar;

    public ProgressBox(Shell parent, final String name) {
        super(parent);
        dialog = new Shell(parent, SWT.APPLICATION_MODAL | SWT.TITLE); 
        dialog.setSize(400,64);
        dialog.setText(name);
        dialog.setLayout(new FillLayout());
        bar = new ProgressBar(dialog, SWT.SMOOTH);
    }

    public void playScript() {
        this.bar.setMaximum(10);

        this.dialog.open();

        final Display display = dialog.getDisplay();
        display.asyncExec(new Runnable() { //asyncExec syncExec
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(1000); // To simulate a task execution
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
                        bar.setSelection(i+1);
                        display.sleep();
                    }
                } finally {
                    dialog.close();
                }
            }
        });
        while (!dialog.isDisposed()) { 
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The main class :

```
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;

public class MainWindow {

    protected Shell shell;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            MainWindow window = new MainWindow();
            window.open();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void open() {
        Display display = Display.getDefault();
        shell = new Shell();
        shell.setSize(450, 300);
        shell.open();
        shell.layout();

        ProgressBox progressBox = new ProgressBox(shell, "Test");
        progressBox.playScript();

        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Can you please post a complete example? So that we can just copy/paste it and directly see what the problem is? Also which OS are you using?

Comment: I updated, now it's directly testable. I am on Windows 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is a combination of these two:

1. You have two event loops (the `while (!X.isDisposed())` part)
2. You're blocking the UI by using `Thread.sleep()` on the main thread.

Point 2 causes your application to be unresponsive to user interactions while the progress bar is shown, e.g. the user can't focus the window anymore.

Also note, that (at least for the code you have so far) a `Dialog` isn't necessary. I've attached a code example that shows how you can do two things:

1. Have a modal window on top of your main window
2. Update the UI periodically using `Display#timerExec(int, Runnable)`

```
protected ProgressBar bar;
protected Shell       shell;

public ProgressBox(Shell parent, final String name)
{
    this.shell = new Shell(parent, SWT.APPLICATION_MODAL | SWT.TITLE);
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    bar = new ProgressBar(shell, SWT.SMOOTH);

    shell.setText(name);
    shell.pack();
    shell.open();
}

public void open()
{
    final int max = 10;

    this.bar.setMaximum(max);

    new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= max; i++)
            {
                if (bar == null || bar.isDisposed())
                {
                    closeShell();
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    final int index = i;
                    shell.getDisplay().asyncExec(new Runnable()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void run()
                        {
                            bar.setSelection(index);
                        }
                    });
                }

                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e)
                {
                    closeShell();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            closeShell();
        }

        private void closeShell()
        {
            shell.getDisplay().asyncExec(new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    shell.close();
                }
            });
        }
    }).start();
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Display display = Display.getDefault();
    Shell shell = new Shell();
    shell.setSize(450, 300);
    shell.open();

    new ProgressBox(shell, "Progress").open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for these info, that could put me on the way. The problem is that I have a ordered list of tasks to execute, that's why I have a loop and a Thread.sleep to simulate it. So if I replace the timerExec in your example I have the same problem or no responding dialog problem

Comment: @Gnervey Then you should start a new thread and only wrap the actual UI interaction in an asyncExec call.

Comment: @Gnervey You might want to have a look at the `ProgressMonitorDialog`. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12986912/using-progressmonitordialog-in-eclipse-4-properly) is a related question.

Comment: @Gnervey I've updated my code to use a non-UI-`Thread` and only wrap the UI interactions in `asyncExec` calls.